# Python reset loop of large csv file

Tags: csv, for-loop

I have to loop over a large csv file multiple times (for loop) and I reset the loop with seek(0). I have to search one line of another csv file in this file. It works for a few iterations but then it  starts to get very slow and I have the impression it hangs up after a while. Is there a better solution to do this?

My code looks like this:

```
   import csv

   CsvFile1 = 'path1'
   CsvFile2 = open('path2','rb')
   csv2 = csv.reader(CsvFile2, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ',')

    with open(CsvFile1,'rb') as CSV1:
        csv1 = csv.reader(CsvFile1, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ',')
        for row1 in csv1:
            CsvFile2.seek(0)
            for row2 in csv2:
                if row1[3] == row2[3]:
                  #write row1 in another file
```

Comment: how big is the csv actually? Which programming language are you using? If you use linux, you could consider splitting the csv file into chunks - worth considering if you need to search for a particular line only. Or simply to use grep function in linux and pipe the found line into another text file.

Comment: If I remember correctly the file is about 70'000 KB. I'm working with python windows not linux. I have to compare several lines from file1 (I have certain conditions which ones) with the lines from this file 2. and to make sure I find everything I have to reset (it is not necessary to go to the beginning of the file. One line back would be enough)